# pecl/mongo requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0, version <= 5.99.99), installed version is 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 No valid packages found install failed

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, lampp

I would to connect lampp to mongodb so I need to install mongodb client , I do `sudo pecl install mongo` il m'affiche le message suivant :

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongo.so: undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mongo.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mongo.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 WARNING: "pecl/mongo" is deprecated in favor of "channel:///mongodb" pecl/mongo requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0, version <= 5.99.99), installed version is 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 No valid packages found install failed, please how to correct this error

Answer (score 16):

`mongo` is the old driver which is not compatible with PHP 7, you need to use new driver `mongodb`.

Comment: Thinks, can you tell me how I use the new driver mongodb

Comment: Thinks I do under the folder /opt/lampp/bin : sudo pecl install mongodb, and it works :)

Comment: Now, I try to test connection xampp with database mongodb, so I create a file sample.php which contains this code : <?php
echo "<h2>Connection to database successfully</h2>";
  $m=new MongoClient();
  echo "<h2>Connection to database successfully</h2>";

  $db=$m -> loginproject;
   echo "<h2>database $db successfully</h2>";
?>

Comment: when I run localhost/sample.php I find this error: Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sample.php on line 3;               please help me to correct this error

Comment: Have you read the docs I linked? `MongoClient` is from OLD driver and it's not available in new one

Comment: Example of usage `pecl install -f mongodb-stable` from https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 3):

It's easy all you have to do is change it to 
`sudo pecl install mongodb`